# nginx container not connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, devops

I have deployed a nginx container, and I exposed port 8080:80, but when I do a curl localhost:8080, I get "Recv failure: Connection reset by peer". I have allowed an inbound rule with port 8080 to allow incoming traffic to go through to the container.

[image]

Comment: Your host 8080 is connected to the container's 8080.

Comment: As @Lamanus said, there is someting wrong there. Could you share the comand you use to run the container?

Comment: Please share your docker run command

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Hugo Calderon,

I didn't find any code from you but I'd like to add a good example here, explaining how to start a simple Nginx server.

**My structure directory**

```
|____nginx
| |____Dockerfile
| |____default.conf
|____docker-compose.yml
```

**./docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services: 
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
```

**nginx/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        return 200 'Hello world!';
    }
}
```

**nginx/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Execute the following commands.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The previous command will run a `nginx` container

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

After execute curl you should get a message like the following.

```
Hello world!
```

If you need to change the message or add new logic in `default.conf` file make sure to run `docker-compose build` command, after that, you should run again `docker-compose up -d`, finally the new change will be added in the container.

I hope will be useful to you and other users!